# jQuery no loading inside Ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Thank you for your help.

My jQuery code doesn't load inside ajax content.

Index.html :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#gps").load("find.php"); 
});
</script>
```

/index.html#!/gallery.html

```
<div id="gps"><center>Loading...</center></div>
```

Network tab on gallery.html

```
 http://localhost/gallery-3col.html

GET /gallery-3col.html HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:41.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/41.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://localhost/index.html
Connection: keep-alive
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 08 Oct 2015 00:06:37 GMT
If-None-Match: "30c-5218ca2fa3d40"

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Date: Thu, 08 Oct 2015 00:34:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1j PHP/5.5.19 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Etag: "30c-5218ca2fa3d40"
```

Thank you for your answers ;-)
Alex

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Can I know why my div can't load ?

Comment: What does the network tab show with the Ajax call?

Comment: What does the network tab show with the **Ajax call** ? (isn't that find.php)

Comment: i don't understand :$ how to see the network tab... :(

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: I am on firebug on network tab but i see nothing. I'm uploading online my website.

Comment: Here the online website : http://umberto073.cloudapp.net/ajax/ajax/#!/index.html

Comment: If you go to this link without ajax :  http://umberto073.cloudapp.net/ajax/ajax/gallery-3col.html it's working

Comment: Use a tool like fiddler and check what is the HTTP request and response.

Comment: Your code does not work because you try to use jQuery before you add it to the page!!!!!! The developer console has the error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

Comment: No, i added jQuery : <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> on every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help.

Is someone can check :

http://umberto073.cloudapp.net/ajax/ajax/#!/index.html (Click on It, then Menu on left, then Gallery)

The page should load a div (with .load jQuery) like This one :

http://umberto073.cloudapp.net/ajax/ajax/gallery-3col.html